# Using jQuery UI Dialog with Backbone.js and RequireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js, requirejs

I would like to do popups on my first webpage which using a backbone.

```
define(['jquery',
'jqueryui',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'api',
'text!' + versions.getVersionedPath('templates/form.html')

 function ($, jqueryui, _, Backbone, Api, Form) {
    var widok = Backbone.View.extend({
        formularz: _.template(Form),
        el: 'body',
        events: {
            'click #test': 'test',
            'click .del': 'usun',
            'click #elo': 'test2'
        },
        initialize: function () {
            this.$el.html(this.formularz());
            self = this;
            console.log('This model has been initialized.');
            this.render();
        },
        render: function () {
            console.log('Showing up');
                    this.$el.html(this.formularz());
        },
        test: function () {
            self.showNews();
            return false;

        },
        test2: function () {
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height: 140,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Delete all items": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

    return {initialize: function () {
            console.log('Initialize');
            new widok;
            self.showNews();
            console.log('blablablablabla');
        }};

});
```

I have function like this, but when I'm trying to use it I had error like

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function.
```

I have defined jquery and jqueryui. Someone could help me ?

Have it on requirejs config

```
shim: {
  jqueryui: {
    "deps": ['jquery']
  },
```

Comment: Have you defined shim for jQuery UI? Please post the requirejs config.

Comment: Yes, I've defined shim for jQuery UI :)

Comment: jQuery Ui doesn't really export anything, so it's better to add it as the last. Maybe the path is wrong or something? BTW what version of jQuery UI are you using?

Comment: im using 2.1.1 version

Comment: @nEJVI There's no such thing? latest version is like `~1.11.0`..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you shared has syntax errors, you're not closing the dependency array.

jQuery UI supports AMD from version `1.11.0`. Here's a [guide](http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/environments/amd/) for using it with AMD loaders.

So if you're using the latest versions then remove the `shim` from configuration.

also note that `jqueryui` in your module will be `undefined` since it doesn't export anything, so it's better to add such things at the end of dependencies like:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'api',
  'text!' + versions.getVersionedPath('templates/form.html'),
  'jqueryui'],
function ($, _, Backbone, Api, Form) {});
```